# SenGrid asking more further information while signup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am new in this field. Can anyone help me that what should I mention in the given below asking details by SendGrid while signup

[image: SendGrid needed information while signup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reply as per your details.

Q1. You can send if you are developer just 100-200 emails daily

Q2. You can explain your method, if you are using for development purpose simply let them know that you will use it in development.

Q3. If you are developer, and using for development let them know you are not collection any email. But if you want to use in future than you can tell them you will add unsubscribe method to so people can unsubscribe it.

Q4. If you are developer than it will be Transactional, and if you want to spam, it is really useless to use it for marketing, but you can mention it.

Please note sendgrid has their good mechanism to find spammer, so you can't use for spamming. For development purpose it is good.